# Access same elements of matrices in a list R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices of same dimensions in R. I would like to access same element of each matrix at a time.

For example:

```
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), byrow=T, ncol=3)
b <- matrix(c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1), byrow=T, ncol=3)
c <- matrix(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,2,8,5), byrow=T, ncol=3)
d <- list(a, b, c)
```

I would like to sequentially access a[1,1], b[1,1], c[1,1] together, then a[1,2], b[1,2], c[1,2] ...

Comment: do you mean the result of `a==b`?

Comment: @Waldi For n matrices in a list, I need to check if corresponding elements of different matrices are same.

Comment: Can you show the expected output given your example?

Comment: @markus I don't know if can show the expected output but.. In a row, if the element in same column number of each matrix is same, e.g. if a[1,3], b[1,3] and c[1,3] are same, I would cbind row 1 of each of these matrices in a new matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and clearest way would be to create two nested loops:

```
for(i in 1:3) {
    for(j in 1:3) {
        print(a[i, j] == b[i, j])
    }
 }
```

But given your question you could simply compare matrices with this. This verfies if two matrices are the same:

```
all(a == b)
```

Now you can also loop through a list of matrices. You called that list `d`:

```
for(x in d) {
    for(y in d) {
        print(all(x == y))
    }
 }
```

However, if you insist on checking the values in the exact order you specified, you can access them with an `sapply`.

```
for(i in 1:3)
  for(j in 1:3)
    print( sapply(d, `[`, i, j) )
```

Now, let us finally check if all elements are the same:

```
Same <- NULL
for(i in 1:3)
  for(j in 1:3) {
    s <- length(unique(sapply(d, `[`, i, j))) == 1
    print( length(unique(sapply(d, `[`, i, j))) == 1 )
    Same <- c(Same, s)
  }
 print(Same)
```

Comment: This will enable me to check elements of a single matrix only. My problem is different. I need to check corresponding elements of all the matrices together.

Comment: By corresponding elements I don't mean the entire matrix, but corresponding element at a given index like [2,5] of each matrix.

Comment: Which is what the third approach gives you. It loops through the row & column indices and compares the values at the position [i, j].

Comment: The last one works well for my purpose, except I don't need to print the output. Instead I would like to take them in a variable. Could you help with that?